# Redis for php 5.4 got fatal error Class 'Redis' not found in Windows machine

Tags: php, redis

I'm using php 5.4.12 which installed extension php_redis and php_igbinary that was downloaded at https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/downloads.

There are 2 version: thread version and non thread version. First i try with the first one. Copy 2 file php_redis and php_igbinary to ext folder of php, edit php.ini config for load extension and seem to successful

[image]

After that, i run myfile.php that has command: $redis = new Redis(); -> it got fatal error: CLASS REDIS IS NOT FOULD.

I have tried with others version (non thread) but i got similar.

Anybody know about this

Tks in advance

**UPDATE:** 
I look at apache error log. Got this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library   'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_igbinary.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_redis.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: This looks like a version mismatch between your php and client extension. Please check for the version compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version mismatch. You're using the `64-bit php_redis.dll` instead of the 32-bit. Download and paste the 32-bit version for php 5.3-5.6 from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/2.2.7/windows) into your `php/ext` folder and add the following line to your `php.ini`:

```
extension=php_redis.dll
```

Versions for php 7.0-7.1 can be found at: https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/3.1.0/windows

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the `.dll` [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/5.2.1/windows). It only worked when choosing the thread-safe (TS) one.

Comment: Latest link as of 06/2023: https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/5.3.7/windows

Answer (score -1):

It is important to pay attention to the correct version of PHP.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30682225)